# Generate OpenAPI spec from gin project

Tags: go, swagger, openapi, go-gin

Is there a way to generate OpenAPI spec files from a gin project? This issue is really hard to search for, all I could find so far are on doing there reverse.

Answer (score 2):

[gin-swagger](https://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger) is extracting comments from  your code.

Running `swag init` generates :

- docs.go: To serve SwaggerUI pages
- swagger.json: The Swagger Specification in json file format.
- swagger.yaml: The Swagger Specification in yaml file format.

Comment: This project still generates Swagger v2 specifications. Do you know how to get v3?

Answer (score 1):

You mean API docs for API user?

I saw you tag the question with `swagger`.

You have two chooses:

1. [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger)

> This package contains a golang implementation of Swagger 2.0 (aka OpenAPI 2.0): it knows how to serialize and deserialize swagger specifications.

2. [swag](https://github.com/swaggo/swag)

> Swag converts Go annotations to Swagger Documentation 2.0. We've created a variety of plugins for popular Go web frameworks. This allows you to quickly integrate with an existing Go project (using Swagger UI).

What difference between them?

Here is the answer from [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger):

> The main difference at this moment is that this one actually works...
>
> The swagger-codegen project (like `swag`) only generates a workable go client and even there it will only support flat models. Further, the go server generated by swagger-codegen is mostly a stub.

Detail of this answer in [How is this different from go generator in swagger-codegen?](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger#how-is-this-different-from-go-generator-in-swagger-codegen)
 from [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger).